# JS Object destructuring inside new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to achieve this with object destructuring but can't quite figure out the right syntax:

Without destructuring:

```
  this.$store.dispatch('user/login', {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password
  })
```

With destructuring (doesnt work):

```
  this.$store.dispatch('user/login', {
    { username, password } = this
  })
```

What's the right syntax here?

Comment: That's an object parameter to a function. What are you trying to "destructure"??

Comment: may be take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused. There is nothing to "destructure" here - your `dispatch` function simply takes an object parameter with 2 properties (`username` and `password`).

You could define this object before calling it like:

```
var input = {username:this.username,password:this.password};
this.$store.dispatch('user/login', input);
```

Or, as your current object has the right properties you could simply pass `this`

```
this.$store.dispatch('user/login', this);
```

It's worth going though the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on destructuring to understand it.